# How to create the delay of 1 sec before set the alpha of View?

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation, layout-animation

In My Application i am going to set the alpha after one animation.
As like:

```
hideMenu = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getApplication(), R.anim.menu_layout_hide);
 menuLayout.startAnimation(hideMenu);
 menuLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But i want to set the delay of 1 Sec before the Alpha set th the View. as Because of that i am not able to see the Animation of that layout. So How it is possibe ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71824377/12272687

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In your animation `xml` file you can use `android:startOffset` attribute:

```
android:startOffset int. The amount of milliseconds the animation delays after start() is called.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try it.

Comment: if you do not mind , not making sense postDelayed in animation because animation itself have setStartDelay method.Please do not take my word as offense but i tell you what i feel.

Answer (score 80):

Can't you use the

> android:startOffset int. The amount of milliseconds the animation
>   delays after start() is called.

in your animation xml?

See [the animation resource documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).

Answer (score 29):

Suppose you are using the view `.animate()` method, you can set the start offset:

```
view.animate().x(100)
              .setDuration(5000)
              .setStartDelay(1000);
```

Answer (score 10):

Handler is a good technique to achieve this.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     view.startAnimation(animation);
   }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 8):

In your case you can simply do like this

```
hideMenu = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getApplication(), R.anim.menu_layout_hide);

hideMenu.setStartOffset(1000);

 menuLayout.startAnimation(hideMenu);
 menuLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In this case you can control dynamically value of the start time from the activity