# How to start a function when animation has ended?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two functions that animate two different TextViews but they both seem to start at the same time but I am trying to have the animation of the first function finish first and then start the second function.

```
public Boolean functionFinished = false;


public void runFunction(){
    firstFunction();
    if(functionFinished = true){
       secondFunction();
    }

}


public void firstFunction(){

        initialCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Fade);

        initialCount.setText("3");
        final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        out.setDuration(1000);
        initialCount.startAnimation(out);

        out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if(initialCount.getText().equals("3")){
                    initialCount.setText("2");
                    initialCount.startAnimation(out);
                } else if(initialCount.getText().equals("2")){
                    initialCount.setText("1");
                    initialCount.startAnimation(out);
                } else if (initialCount.getText().equals("1")){
                    initialCount.setText("START!");

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
   functionFinished = true;
}
```

The second function simply changes its own textView every second counting up from 0.

What did I do wrong / how do I correct this so that the second function runs after the first function has finished? (ie. sets functionFinished to true only when the TextView from the firstFunction is "START!")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void runFunction() {
    firstFunction();
}

public void firstFunction() {
    initialCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Fade);

    initialCount.setText("3");
    final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    out.setDuration(1000);

    out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ...
            secondFunction();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    initialCount.startAnimation(out);
}
```

Just call second function from `onAnimationEnd`. Also keep in mind that you should attach listener before start animation.

Comment: @Divers! I have a similar question, can you help me? Because I have tried with AnimationListener and it doesn't work! My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987892/how-to-add-delay-between-animations

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. You helped me a lot @Divers :)

Answer (score 1):

If your minimum sdk version is 14:-

```
textView1.animate()
         .alpha(0f)
         .setDuration(400)
         .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() { 
          @Override 
          public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
               // animate second textview here....
          } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign `functionFinished = true` at the end of the firstFunction().

And you must misunderstand that  `initialCount.startAnimation(out)` will block the code and `firstFunction()` completes only after animation ends .

`initialCount.startAnimation(out)` will not block any code ,and  `functionFinished = true` is run immediately. so  `secondFunction()` will run immediately after  `firstFunction()` finishes instead of animation finishes.